# Unable to get out in Required format from awk

Tags: awk

I am having log lines like

```
{"name":"Test","ip":"ip-ip-ip-ip","pid":30536,"level":30,"msg":"Result For Test Id 123 : 400","time":"2016-01-04T09:26:26.743Z","v":1}
```

I want the output in the following format

```
123,400,2016-01-04T09:26:26.743Z
```

I have come up with this

```
cat test.log| grep "Result For Test Id" | awk '{split($0,a,","); print a[5] a[6] }'
```

This is giving the output

```
"msg":"Result For Test Id 123 : 400""time":"2016-01-04T09:26:26.743Z"
```

I am not able to get the output from this.

Please help.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use just sed with extended regex support (-r or -E switch) and regex groups:

```
$ a=$'{"name":"Test","ip":"ip-ip-ip-ip","pid":30536,"level":30,"msg":"Result For Test Id 123 : 400","time":"2016-01-04T09:26:26.743Z","v":1}'
$ sed -r 's/(.*Test Id )(.[^:]*)( : )(.[^"]*)(.*time":")(.[^"]*)(.*)/\2,\4,\6/g' <<<"$a"   #replace <<<"$a" with 'yourfile' (without <<<)
# Output:
123,400,2016-01-04T09:26:26.743Z
```

Regex Explanation:

```
Basic sed usage       ----> s/oldvalue/newvalue/ : Substitutes oldvalue with newvalue
Group 1 (.*Test Id )  ----> Match everything from beginning up to:     'Test Id + space'  
Group 2 (.[^:]*)      ----> next, match everything that follows Test Id excluding ':' => up to first found ':' => matches '123'  
Group 3 ( : )         ----> next, match 'space:space'  
Group 4 (.[^"]*)      ----> next, match all chars exluding '"' => up to first found '"' => matches '400'   
Group 5 (.*time":")   ----> next, matches all chars up to:   'time":"'  
Group 6 (.[^"]*)      ----> next match whatever follows previous group up to first " ==> 2016-01-04T09:26:26.743Z 
Group 7 (.*)          ----> next match all the rest chars  
/\2,\4,\6/g           ----> replace the whole input / original stream with regex groups 2,4 and 6. midifier 'g' in the end means global replacements.
```

Offcourse similar operations can be done in gnu awk:

```
awk '{match($0,/(.*Test Id )(.[^:]*)( : )(.[^"]*)(.*time":")(.[^"]*)(.*)/,f);print f[2]","f[4]","f[6]}' <<<"$a"
```

match function of awk, splits the line ($0) into pieces / regex groups , and the results of each group is stored in an array f

Comment: Thank you for the answer and explanation

Answer (score 0):

Command is:

```
cat test.log | grep "Result For Test Id" | awk -F "," '{print $5,$6}' | awk -F "\"" '{print $4,$8}' | awk -F " " '{print $5","$7","$8}'
```

result :

```
123,400,2016-01-04T09:26:26.743Z
```

Comment: GNU awk (available in almost every modern Linux Distro) supports multicharacters as delimiter. You don't need all those pipes. You can just do `awk -F "[,\" ]" '{print $24","$26","$31}'`, by defining delimiter to be `,` or `"` or `space` .